# Rails 3: Sorting array through a link in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an @array and a view where each array element is listed. Right next to that list I want a link which says "Sort by rank".

I know how to sort an array by a certain attibute

```
array.sort {| a, b | a[:rank] <=> b[:rank] }
```

But I don't know what I have to put in the view and controller, so it displays me the sorted array as soon as I click the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you create a parameter that re-loads the page with the appropriate filter engaged:

```
<%= link_to('Sort', :order => 'rank') %>
```

Then in your controller you have something that re-sorts the list if required:

```
if (params[:order] == 'rank')
  @array.sort_by!(&:rank)
end
```

There are plug-ins that will make this easier, plus you should probably be doing the sorting in the database if you have pagination.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed. Just out of curiousity ... which plugins exactly? Because I couldn't find anything through google.

Comment: I generally use [searchlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) if I use anything, but there are some that go so far as to create sortable tables. It really depends on your specific requirements.